# Row number regexp_split_to_table

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, row-number

I have this request :

```
 select
    narttx,
    LIBETX
    --,row_number() over (partition by narttx)
from
(select
        codearticle_article as NARTTX,
        regexp_split_to_table(valeur_article_libelles, E'\x0b') as LIBETX
    from
        article.article a
    join article.article_libelles bl on
        bl.idarticle = a.idarticle
    and typelibelle_article_libelles = 'descriptifTech'
) vue
where   
narttx = '5627811' 
or 
narttx = '5627819'
```

It output this :

```
5627819 Finition
5627819 du
5627819 produit
...
5627811 Largeur (en cm) 
5627811 Hauteur (en cm)
5627811 Matière principale
...
```

I want to add the row number and reset it when the narttx change.
So I uncomment the "--,row_number() over (partition by narttx)" part.

I should have :

```
5627819 Finition 1
5627819 du       2
5627819 produit  3
...
5627811 Largeur (en cm) 1
5627811 Hauteur (en cm) 2
5627811 Matière principale 3
...
```

But it don't work, the order is incorrect :

```
5627811 Largeur (en cm) 1
5627811 Hauteur (en cm) 2
5627811 Matière principale 3
...
5627819 Largeur 1
5627819 du  2
5627819 corps   3
5627819 de  4
5627819 meuble  5
...
5627819 Finition    110
5627819 de  111
5627819 prise   112
...
```

If I select just one article :

```
where   
narttx = '5627811'
```

It works well, but when I put two of them, the order is incorrect...

Why ?

Comment: Changing a question after someone has answered, invalidating that answer is something rude... But anyways, now your question is confusing as the `row_number()` is commented out... Assuming this is another mistake, there is no "incorrect" order as the `OVER` clause doesn't contain an `ORDER BY` clause, so *any* order is correct. The same applies to the overall query and the order of the records themselves.

Comment: I don't wanted to invalidate anything, just correct my question to be more clear, sorry. I tried to add a order by clause after the partition by, but it does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `regexp_split_to_array()` to the `from` clause (where it belongs), then you can use `with ordinality` which will automatically return the array index:

```
select
    narttx,
    libetx, 
    rn
from (select
        codearticle_article as narttx,
        v.*
    from
        article.article a
    join article.article_libelles bl 
          on bl.idarticle = a.idarticle
      and typelibelle_article_libelles = 'descriptifTech'
      cross join regexp_split_to_table(valeur_article_libelles, E'\x0b') with ordinality as v(libetx, rn)
) vue
where   
narttx = '5627811' 
or 
narttx = '5627819'
```

Comment: Thank you a lot !!!! It works great, it made me crazy before, and now it's perfect. I can't understand why it would not work before but nevermind :)